CsvHelper no longer has Context.IsFieldBad
I'm upgrading a program from CsvHelper v2.15.0 to v33.0.1 and dealing with all the changes.  I've fixed most of them, but I can't find the solution to this.  In my old code I have:
while (csv.Read() && !csv.Context.IsFieldBad)
 {
   ..
 }

This worked in v2.15, but in v33, IsFieldBad is no longer a member of the Context, and I can't find anything online that discusses this issue.  I've gone thought the CsvHelper Migration steps, as well as the overall Change Log, and even peered into the source, and nothing mentions this breaking change (that I can see or understand).
What would be the equivalent to this code for the latest CsvHelper version?

Wouldn't it be better to ask the developer on GitHub?

@EtiennedeMartel Possibly, but that would require creating a GitHub account just for that. Plus I've seen him also answer questions on here.

I'm not positive on this, but I believe IsFieldBad was removed in favor of throwing a BadDataException. To upgrade this code, you would need to wrap the while loop in a try/catch. And depending on what IsFieldBad used to cover, you may also have to catch MissingFieldException.
try
{
    while (csv.Read())
    {
        var record = csv.GetRecord<Foo>();

        results.Add(record);

    }
}
catch (BadDataException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("BadDataFound on row " + ex.Context.Parser.Row);
}

If you didn't want to have an exception thrown, you could use the BadDataFound property in CsvConfiguration to set your own IsFieldBad variable. The difference being that csv.Read() doesn't throw the BadDataException. That happens when you actually try to access the data with something like csv.GetRecord<T>(). Depending on what IsFieldBad used to cover, you might also have to set MissingFieldFound in CsvConfiguration.
void Main()
{
    var data = @"Id,Name
1,Good Name
2,Bad "" Name
3,Another Good Name";

    var isFieldBad = false;
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        BadDataFound = row => {
            isFieldBad = true;
            Console.WriteLine("BadDataFound on row " + row.Context.Parser.Row);
        }       
    };

    var reader = new StringReader(data);
    using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config);
    
    csv.Read();
    csv.ReadHeader();
    
    var results = new List<Foo>();
    
    while (csv.Read())
    {
        var record = csv.GetRecord<Foo>();
        
        if (isFieldBad)
        {
            isFieldBad = false;
            continue;
        }

        results.Add(record);        
    }
    
    results.Dump();
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


D'oh, I'm looking the second example and I did see examples like that online, but totally missed that you have to manually reset isBadField (and that confused me).

If you wanted to keep going you could use continue instead of break or for the first example, put your try/catch inside the while loop.

I already have a BadDataFound closure, so I'll add my own isBadField flag.

I just updated the 2nd example after realizing you would never hit the isFieldBad = false; after having setting it to true the way the code was written.

My testing would have found that!  But thanks for helping me see the obvious

And to continue along on the same theme of cluelessness, I just realized I've spent the last 2 days editing the wrong damn git branch /s
